# appengine custom 404 page for static website

Tags: google-app-engine, error-handling, http-status-code-404

I am trying to host a simple static website on Google AppEngine, but I have a problem with setting up a custom 404 page.

My `app.yaml` serves static files (from `www` subdir) for all requests:

```yaml
application: id
version: v
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
default_expiration: "1d"
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: (.*)/
  static_files: www\1/index.html
  upload: www/index.html
- url: /
  static_dir: www

error_handlers:
- file: 404.html
```

but while trying to access a file that does not exist, I do not see the 404.html, but the default GAE error message.

Logs show:

```
Static file referenced by handler not found: www/does-not-exists/index.html
```

or

```
Static file referenced by handler not found: www/does-not-exists.html
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work.  You static handler will match most things, and you can not do a error_handler for a 404.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that it is a dead end. Any suggestions on how I could get custom 404 pages on GAE for static site?

Comment: Add a dynamic handler (code) as the last handler defined in app.yaml, if it falls through to there then you can put up a customer 404 page.  But you you primary static handler regex will need to be more specific other wise you will continue to get the current error as the regex matches everything.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error as well, and I basically caught it by using an base exception handler (I was using spring, so this was easy) to catch all exceptions (that weren't caught already) to redirect to an error page.